# get order id on observer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-grid

this may seem a duplicate but I couldn't find one and been struggling with for quite some time now.

I'm extending Order Grid with a Column on Admin panel.

I have `core_layout_block_create_after` observer which, when called, `addColumnAfter` on `$block = $observer->getBlock();` in my Observer's method:

```
 $block = $observer->getBlock();
    // how do I bind order id on this link
    $link = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/mymodule/index');
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
        $block->addColumnAfter('action_cool_api',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Cool Test'),
                'index' => 'action_cool_api',
                'type' => 'action',
                'actions'  => array(
                    array(
                        'url'     => $link,
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Cool'),
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'status'
        );
    }
```

How do I bind order id on every link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php

$block = $observer->getBlock();
    // how do I bind order id on this link
    $link = array('base'=>'*/mymodule/index');
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
        $block->addColumnAfter('action_cool_api',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Cool Test'),
                'index' => 'action_cool_api',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'type' => 'action',
                'actions'  => array(
                    array(
                        'url'     => $link,
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Cool'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id',
                        'data-column' => 'action',
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'status'
        );
    }
```

Hope this work .

Comment: doesn't work. are you sure it's for Magento 1.9

Comment: i tried with `real_order_id` which is the real order column name, but it still didn't work

Comment: Yes it is , check app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid ,

methode : 

$this->addColumn which add the view action to the order grid. 

It should work the same way.

Comment: I am glad you could find the way to go :) , i have updated my answer as well :) .